# rails3 devise - no route matches "/sessions/user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authorization, devise

it is the first time I am working with devise and I am a confused by the massive amount of files and configuration options.
Before installing devise, I used the nifty:authentication from ryan bates - which I didn't delete before installing devise and I guess now my routes and/or controllers are a little screwed up.

well, after singing in on /users/sign_in devise tries to redirect me to

```
http://localhost:3000/sessions/user
```

but I get the error:

```
No route matches "/sessions/user"
```

I don't know where is the error, any help appreciated

I put all the relevant code in a gist: https://gist.github.com/972058

thanks in advance

Comment: fwiw i solved it by making a complete rollback of the nifty:authorization which I used before. (rails destroy nifty:authorization)

After I generated again the user model and controller and cleaned up the routes a little and it works now.

Comment: can you post your config/routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have root path in your routes. As you can read in devise page: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

> After signing in a user, confirming
>   the account or updating the password,
>   Devise will look for a scoped root
>   path to redirect. Example: For a :user
>   resource, it will use user_root_path
>   if it exists, otherwise default
>   root_path will be used. This means
>   that you need to set the root inside
>   your routes

To specify redirect page you need to do this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

btw. you don't need sessions controller to make it works

Comment: I have already root :to => "pages#index"
in my routes file (line 88 in the gist routes.rb) - doesn't seem to work

Comment: then try to specify redirect page for sign_in. I guess it doesn't work because of sessions controller which isn't connected with users and doesn't have user method inside so it's not to possieble to find sessions/user(but I don't know why devise redirect there ;/ try this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: Thanks Greg I tried that but without success... still getting the same error. It must have something to do with this line in the views/devise/session/new.html.erb "<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| "

Comment: because url => session_path(resource_name) will be /session/user and it doesn't exist. When I change this path the redirect works but devise doesn't log me in

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a session controller which was causing issues. Removing resources :sessions from the routes file should solve the problem. That was because I had previously created a session manager. Once gone, I did not see the issue again.